# Running Perl 5 on Centos 7 and trying to install abd use gtk / gtk2

Tags: linux, perl, gtk, centos7

Someone may notice this is an almost identical question I posted a few days ago regarding tcl / tk.  The original recommendation (that worked for this particular error) does not seem to remedy the same error condition that I am currently seeing when attempting to use gtk / gtk2.

I have attempted to switch from tk to gtk because there were subsequent problems with tk that I simply wasn't been able to resolve.

In case it is important, all I am trying to do is Use a GUI from a Perl script.

The remedy for the tk problem was to install tk-devel using yum.

I'm not finding a gtk-devel package, But I did find this on the net, which I did.

```
sudo yum install gtk* gtk+*
```

I have also update my perl installation to the current level via yum.

Anyway, when I invoke my test script which has one line in the form of

```
use Gtk;
```

or gtk, Gtk2, gtk2 I see the error

> Can't locate Gtk.pm in @Inc (file list...)

I am not sure why the original tk issue was fixed by the inclusion of tk-devel and why I have been unable to do the same with the gtk package?  Or maybe there is an additional issue involved?

Answer (score 3):

---

»» `use Gtk;` «« : Better → `use Gtk2;`

Gtk.pm is for the ancient gtk+ -1.2.10 : Year 2002? No CentOS 7 packages, perl-Gtk.

Please do : # yum install perl-Gtk2

Provides /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Gtk2.pm

---

Generally : Please use the 'yum provides */[file]' command to decide package names :

Like `# yum provides */Gtk2.pm`

---

[gtk2.pm](/questions/tagged/gtk2.pm)

---

Comment: I tried these and saw the following.  Am I missing something?

sudo yum install perl-Gtk2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
No package perl-Gtk2 available.
Error: Nothing to do


sudo yum provides */Gtk2.pm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror-centos.hostingswift.com
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: centos.sonn.com
No matches found

Answer (score 3):

---

Right, a lot of the common packages are in the epel.repo : Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Download 'epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm' https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

And install with `# cd Downloads/ && yum install epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm`

---

[epel](/questions/tagged/epel)